# Getting existing value for NEW.colname in MySQL trigger if I didn't update that column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using mysql 8.0.23

My table

```
CRETAE TABLE sample_table(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Let us insert one row

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(col1, col2) VALUES('aaa','bbb');
```

Table after insertion

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | bbb |

Trigger before update the table

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sample_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON sample_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = NEW.col1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

update statement

```
UPDATE sample_table SET col2 = 'ccc' WHERE id = 1;
```

Here I am updating only col2 but I am getting "aaa" for message_text, What is the reason behind it?

I wanted to insert col1 value for each update of only col1.

I can't add check for old.col1 <> new.col1 in the trigger. In some scenario I may get same value then also that value should be inserted to another table.

How to achive this? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You log `col1` which is `aaa`, and you update `col2` why do you expect something different?

Comment: Yes, But I am not logged OLD.col1, I have loogged NEW.col1. I didn't pass any value to it in update statement.

Comment: A trigger does not provide the information which column was not part of the update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLD has **all** the old values of a row and NEW **all** columns.

So check if old and new are different

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sample_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON sample_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.col1 <> NEW.col1 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = NEW.col1;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: In my case I may get same value for col1. Ex: 
`UPDATE sample_table SET col2 = 'ccc', col1 = 'aaa' WHERE id = 1;`
I think your answer will not solve the above scenario right?

Comment: no mysql notice it that it is the same value and will do nothing at all with that column, with that column, but only ask for col1 changes, burt you can male the if cluase much more cpmplex or use CASE WHEN